# Replacing in layered map?

Tags: apex

```
Map<String,Object> Level1 = new Map<String,Object>();
Map<String,Object> Level2 = new Map<String,Object>();
Map<String,Object> Level3 = new Map<String,Object>();
Map<String,Object> Level4 = new Map<String,Object>();
Map<String,Object> Level5 = new Map<String,Object>();
Level1.put('Level2',Level2);
Level2.put('Level3',Level3);
Level3.put('Level4',Level4);
Level4.put('Level5',Level5);
Level5.put('Level6',Level6);
```

What I want to do is put in at a dynamic level is there any way other than doing
Level1.get('Level2').get('Level3').get('Level4').get('Level5').put('NewLevel6',NewLevel6);

ideally something like

```
Level1.put('Level2,Level3,Level4,Level5','NewLevel6',NewLevel6);
```

or

```
Level1.put(new List<String>{'Level2','Level3','Level4','Level5'},'NewLevel6',NewLevel6);
```

Comment: the second option is possible, give me a few minutes to write it down

Comment: @ytiq I'm interested in seeing your implementation 

Comment: well, ye you need a separate method for it)

Comment: @sfdcfox same :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this you can do it

```
public static void putIt(Map<String, Object> result, List<String> mapKeys, Object value) {
    Map<String, Object> currentMap = result;
    for (Integer i = 0; i < mapKeys.size() - 1; i++) {
        String key = mapKeys[i];
        
        if (!currentMap.containsKey(key)) {
            currentMap.put(key, new Map<String, Object>()); 
        }
        currentMap = (Map<String, Object>)currentMap.get(key);
    }
    
    currentMap.put(mapKeys[mapKeys.size() - 1], value);
}

Map<String, Object> container = new Map<String, Object>();

putIt(container, new List<String> {'level1', 'level2', 'level3'} , 4);

System.debug('###JSOn.serializePretty(container) = ' + JSOn.serializePretty(container));
```

Comment: just noticed I forgot to mark this as the answer thank you for your help.

Comment: thanks though) much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no, that's not possible out of the box. But you could write your own methods:

```
public static Object getValueByPath(Map<String, Object> recursive, String[] path, Object value) {
    for(String pathItem: path) {
        if(recursive == null) {
            break;
        }
        Object tempValue = recursive.get(pathItem);
        if(tempValue instanceOf Map<String, Object>) {
            recursive = (Map<String, Object>)((Map<String, Object>)tempValue).get(pathItem);
        }
    }
    return recursive?.get(path[path.size()-1]);
}
public static void putValueByPath(Map<String, Object> recursive, String[] path, Object value) {
    List<String> tempPath = new List<String>(path);
    tempPath.remove(tempPath.size()-1);
    for(String pathItem: tempPath) {
        Object thisPathItem = recursive.get(pathItem);
        if(thisPathItem == null) {
            recursive.put(pathItem, thisPathItem = new Map<String, Object>());
        }
        if(thisPathItem instanceOf Map<String, Object>) {
            recursive = (Map<String, Object>)recursive.get(pathItem);
        } else if(pathItem != path[path.size()-1]) {
            return; // Throw an exception?
        }
    }
    recursive.put(path[path.size()-1], value);
}
```

You could use these as utility methods to build deeply nested structures as you like.

Edited to fix actual syntax.

Comment: isn't it ends up with level + 1? cos you create maps for all keys and then use latest key to put value

Comment: type checking is definitely a good idea though)

Comment: @ytiq The last level just ends up getting overwritten, if I've written this correct. It's very minorly faster IMO, but haven't tested this. Yours looks like a reasonable alternative, too.

Comment: it doesn't( wrote the same first time)) `putValueByPath(container, new List<String> {'level1', 'level2', 'level3'} , 4);` returns ```{"level1": "level2" : {"level3" : {"level3" : 4}}}}```

Comment: @ytiq I fixed it (had a few other issues, too).